Efficiently Finding Nearest Non-Colliding Position for a Rectangle in 2D Space?
I’ve been struggling with a problem related to collision detection and positioning in a 2D space, and I could really use some guidance on achieving good performance.
I have a rectangular boundary (blue). Within this space, there is a list of collidable geometries, including contour lines and other rectangles (marked in red). Additionally, I have other rectangles (marked in green) that must not collide with the red ones.
When a green rectangle collides with a red rectangle, I need to determine the nearest valid positions for the green rectangle that ensures it does not overlap with any of the red rectangles and lines.
EDITED: The green rectangles do not always have the same size. There can be up to 24 green rectangles, while the number of red lines and polygons can exceed 40 or more. The green rectangles are allowed to overlap with each other. Unfortunately, I need to use Python, and I require the performance to ensure that a green rectangle can find its new position in less than half a second.
Background: There is an Web API that allows "configurations" to be added to a queue. Each configuration consists of 2-3 "plates." The process of creating a single configuration should not take several minutes. Essentially, each plate represents a wooden base (with defined bounds) that includes cutouts (in red) and clamping points (in green).

I initially tried using a brute-force method to find the nearest non-colliding positions for the rectangles. However, this approach may lead to performance issues when dealing with a large number of collisions.
Expected Ouput:

The expected output should provide the nearest valid center positions for the green rectangle, categorized by movement along different axes:

Only X-axis: (14.5, 7.5)
Only Y-axis: [(5.5, 14.5)]
Both axes: (4.5, 8.5)


500 milliseconds for each pair collision detection can be easily achieved. Since you need  2,376 collision detections that will be just over 15 minutes.  Is that OK with you?  What performance do you get with your current implementation?

FYI I have added a graphical display of the results of my implementation which is many orders of magnitude faster than your require.  Example posted in my answer below.

" Unfortunately, I need to use Python"  Can you describe what this "need" is?  For someone so concerned about performance, you really need to get away from Python - it is just so painfully slow for any serious work.

If I need this performance using C++, is it possible to bind a C++ method to Python?

Yes.  However, simpler. faster and easier would be to implement the the application in C++.  Suggestion: open an issue in my github repo, describing the format of the 'configurations' and the response you require.

I have added configuration input from a file, so that you can do a quick and easy integration test with your application.  Details in the README https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79039055/blob/main/README.md

I wrote out some code that would guarantee the solution is the smallest displacement of the green rectangle. It would still require some adjusting to apply to your specific problem.
I am assuming you have two functions available: a function to calculate the distance between two points: calculateDist(), and a function to detect collisions with red squares: detectCollisions(). The rect.width and rect.height get the width and height of the green rectangle that needs to move. The collission._border gets the x or y coordinate for that border of the red rectangle.
I don't guarantee it is the most efficient algorithm, but it will be more efficient then brute forcing it.
# fill with original position of rect
originalPosition = (x, y)
# keeps track of positions which are already known so there is no duplicate code
positionsSearched = set()
# sorted list with the position that has the shortest distance to the original rect as the closest
positionsToSearch = [(0, originalPosition, detectCollisions(originalPosition))] # struct = (distance_to_original, position, collisions)[]
# add the original position to the set of already searched
positionsSearched.add(originalPosition)

# loop as long as there are positions to search and the closest searched position still has collisions
while len(positionsToSearch) > 0 and len(positionsToSearch[0][2]) > 0:
    # get and remove first element of sorted list, this is the position closest to the original position due to the sort
    distance, position, collisions = positionsToSearch.pop(0)
    
    # look at all collisions so that later the collision with the shortest solution can be tested first
    for collision in collisions:
        # add the four possible positions to move to to the stack (top of rect, bottom of rect, right of rect, left of rect)
        # the rect.height and rect.width are those of the original rect you are trying to move
        possibleSolutions = [
            (collision.topBorder - rect.height, position[1]),
            (collision.bottomBorder, position[1]),
            (position[0], collision.rightBorder),
            (position[0], collision.leftBorder - rect.width)
        ]

        for possibleSolution in possibleSolutions:
            # if the possible solution was not already added to the positions to search, add it to the positions to search
            if possibleSolution not in positionsSearched and notOutOfBounds(possibleSolution):
                positionsToSearch.append((calculateDist(possibleSolution, originalPosition), possibleSolution, detectCollisions(possibleSolution)))

    # sort on the distance to the original position, this way the closest are evaluated first
    positionsToSearch.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

# check if the positions to search are 0
if(len(positionsToSearch) == 0):
    return ERROR # this means no valid positions were found to move to

valid_closest_position = positionsToSearch[0][1] # if a valid position is found it will be in front of the list



Have you measured the performance?

For the detect_collisions function, I could optimize performance by using a QuadTree, rather than checking every polygon or line for intersections individually.

In this case it may be very efficient to create a k/d tree using the red rectangles

Building a quadtree is expensive.  Once built each search is much faster.  Whether or not it gives a net benefit depends on how many points you have and how many searches you need.  For some performance tests for a range of point and search numbers see https://github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree#performance-test.  We need to know how many green and red rectangles you need to deal with.

24 green rectangle which can be different at size and up to 100 red lines or polygons.

You need to do 2,376 collision detections, using the naive search.  That will take ~ 50 microseconds.  Do you need something faster than that?

How would 0.02 milliseconds per green/red rectangle pair suit you?  That is 50,000 rectangle pairs per second, or 60 microseconds for the 2300 detections you need to run
To achieve this kind of performance with python is not possible - it is far too slow.
I reccomend using C++ for anything that is performance critical.
Here is the collsion detector in C++
/// @brief collision detector with this rectangle
/// @param other rectangle
/// @param[out] overlap avoidance vector if collision occurred ( use to clear the collision )
/// @return true if collsion occurred

bool cRect::isCollision(
    const cRect &other,
    cxy& overlap ) const
{
    // check for centers too far apart
    // for any possibility of a collision
    double d2 = myCenter.dist2(other.myCenter);
    double mind2 = myMaxDim + other.myMaxDim;
    mind2 *= mind2;
    if (d2 > mind2) {
        overlap = cxy(0,0);
        return false;
    }

    // collision possible, check in detail
    bool ret = false;
    double dy = abs(myCenter.y - other.myCenter.y);
    double miny = abs(myHeight + other.myHeight) / 2;
    overlap.y = miny - dy;
    if (dy < miny) 
        ret = true;
    
    double dx = abs(myCenter.x - other.myCenter.x);
    double minx = abs(myWidth + other.myWidth) / 2;
    overlap.x = minx - dx;
    if (dx < minx) 
        ret = true;
    
    if( ! ret )
    {
        // no collision occurred
        overlap = cxy(0,0);
    }

    return ret;
}

The performance test does 10,000 detections with 10 different random locations
void performanceTest()
{
    raven::set::cRunWatch::Start();
    srand(time(NULL));
    cxy overlap;
    cRect A(cxy(0, 0), 10, 20);
    for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
    {
        cxy t(rand() % 30 + 1, rand() % 30 + 1);
        cRect B(t, 1, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            raven::set::cRunWatch aWatcher("collision detector");

            A.isCollision(B,overlap);
        }
    }
    raven::set::cRunWatch::Report();
}

Here are the performance results:
raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
   10000        1.792e-08       0.0001792       collision detector

Here is the result of a run with 24 greens and 40 reds

Complete test application code at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79039055
Here is the performance result for 50 runs of the 24 greens and 40 reds, randomly located for each run.  Average less than 3 milliseconds for each run.
raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
      50        0.0023184       0.11592 dodger


@DavidH FYI I have added boundary enforcement

Below is my implementation that utilizes Python, the Shapely library, and a custom QuadTree class.
from shapely.affinity import translate
from shapely.geometry import (
    Point, MultiPoint,
    LineString, MultiLineString,
    Polygon
)


from app.generation._clamping.quadtree import QuadTree


def round_point(point: Point, precision: int = 6) -> Point:
    """Helper function to round the coordinates of a Point."""
    return Point(round(point.x, precision), round(point.y, precision))


def detect_collisions(collider: Polygon, quad_tree: QuadTree) -> list[Point]:
    intersections: set[Point] = set()

    for collidable in quad_tree.query(collider, []):
        if collider.touches(collidable):
            continue

        intersection = collidable.intersection(collider)

        # Handle different types of intersection results
        if intersection.is_empty:
            continue

        if isinstance(intersection, Point):
            intersections.add(intersection)

        elif isinstance(intersection, MultiPoint):
            intersections.update(intersection.geoms)

        elif isinstance(intersection, LineString) or isinstance(intersection, MultiLineString):
            intersections.update([Point(coord) for coord in intersection.coords])

        elif isinstance(intersection, Polygon):
            intersections.update(Point(coord) for coord in intersection.exterior.coords)

    return list(intersections)


def find_shortest_position(rect: Polygon, quad_tree: QuadTree, boundary: Polygon, axis: int = 0):
    original_position: Point = rect.centroid
    searched: set[Point] = set()
    searched.add(original_position)
    positions_to_search: list[tuple[float, Point, list[Point]]] = [(0, original_position, detect_collisions(rect, quad_tree))]

    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = rect.bounds
    height = max_y - min_y
    width = max_x - min_x

    while len(positions_to_search) > 0 and len(positions_to_search[0][2]) > 0:
        distance, position, collisions = positions_to_search.pop(0)

        for collision_point in collisions:
            possible_solutions: list[Point] = []

            if axis == 0:
                possible_solutions.extend([
                    Point(collision_point.x, collision_point.y + height / 2),  # Top
                    Point(collision_point.x, collision_point.y - height / 2),  # Bottom
                    Point(collision_point.x - width / 2, collision_point.y),  # Left
                    Point(collision_point.x + width / 2, collision_point.y),  # Right
                    Point(collision_point.x - width / 2, collision_point.y + height / 2), # Top-Left
                    Point(collision_point.x + width / 2, collision_point.y + height / 2), # Top-Right
                    Point(collision_point.x - width / 2, collision_point.y - height / 2),  # Bottom-Left
                    Point(collision_point.x + width / 2, collision_point.y - height / 2),  # Bottom-Right
                ])

            if axis == 1:
                possible_solutions.extend([
                    Point(collision_point.x - width / 2, original_position.y),  # Left
                    Point(collision_point.x + width / 2, original_position.y),  # Right
                ])

            if axis == 2:
                possible_solutions.extend([
                    Point(original_position.x, collision_point.y + height / 2), # Top
                    Point(original_position.x, collision_point.y - height / 2), # Bottom
                ])

            for solution in possible_solutions:
                solution = round_point(solution, 2)
                translate_x = solution.x - original_position.x
                translate_y = solution.y - original_position.y
                temp = translate(rect, translate_x, translate_y)
                if solution not in searched and boundary.contains(temp):
                    searched.add(solution)
                    positions_to_search.append((solution.distance(original_position), solution, detect_collisions(temp, quad_tree)))

        positions_to_search.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

    if len(positions_to_search) == 0:
        return None

    return positions_to_search[0][1]

This serves as a solid starting point and can be further refined.

What is the performance?

Its way more efficent than Bruteforce.

We need a number.  I am using microseconds per red/green pair.  You are asking us to provide a more efficient method,  so you need to tell how efficient your method is.   Otherwise we cannot tell if our answer is more efficient or not.
